# Simplification / Concentration Results / Bounds for the Expectation of the Minimum of Two Correlated Random Variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory

## Question,

Please provide any simplifications / bounds / concentration results for the expectation of the minimum of two correlated random variables.

$$E\left[\min\left(X,Y\right)\right]=\text{??}$$

$$E\left[\min\left(X,Y\right)\right]\leq\text{??}$$

$$E\left[\min\left(X,Y\right)\right]\geq\text{??}$$

## Assumptions,

We can assume that $X$, $Y$ have a covariance $\sigma_{XY}$ and are from general distribution, $G\left(x\right)$ and $F\left(y\right)$ respectively.

We can assume that the mean, variance and higher moments exist for both the random variables.

## Related Question on the Maximum,

[Expectation of Maximum of Two Correlated Random Variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2344640/simplification-concentration-results-bounds-for-the-expectation-of-the-maxim)

If there are well known results, please provide references to papers that have detailed steps / derivations.

Comment: The two related questions are not really two different questions: From an answer to either you can deduce an answer to the other.

Comment: @MichaelHardy, Thanks for this clarification. For independent variables, I see that $E[\min(X,Y)]$ = $E[X] + E[Y]-E[\max(X,Y)]$. I was unable to show this for correlated variables.  I actually meant to ask you when edited the question, if the maximum was warranted as a new question.

Comment: Note that $\min\{X,Y\} + \max\{X,Y\} = X+Y.$ That does not depend on whether they are correlated; it doesn't even depend on their being random variables; it's true of any two numbers $X$ and $Y$. But if they're random variables, then $\min+\max$ must have the same expected value as $X+Y$ because $\min+\max$ _is_ $X+Y.$

Comment: @MichaelHardy Thanks, I will delete the maximum question then and add your comment about the relation between maximum / minimum to the question or an appropriate answer later. Unless you suggest that retaining the separate question on the maximum would be helpful in some way.

Comment: Suppose $X$ and $W$ are normally distributed with expectation $0$ and variance $1$, and the pair $(X,W)$ is _jointly_ normal with correlation $\rho.$ Then let $Y = W+100.$ Then $\Pr(X<Y)$ is $0.9999\ldots$ regardless of the value of $\rho.$ And if you put $-100$ in place of $+100$ then the inequality is reversed. But maybe some inequality involving the expected values of $X$ and $Y$, their variances, the max and min of $X$ and $Y,$ and $\rho$ holds in general. $\qquad$

Comment: You may want to try with Markov inequality which will gives you an inequality in terms of the individual CDF and the joint CDF.

Comment: @BGM, Thanks for this suggestion. I am not familiar with the Markov inequality with the joint CDF. Could you please clarify further?